# SQL query to get all rows that have data linked by a FK in another table

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I have three tables: `Station`, `MonthlyNormalData` and `SubArea`. I'm trying to get all stations in a sub area that have at least one monthly data tied to it. With the following query, I am able to get all stations in a sub area, but this is disregarding the part about monthly data ($region is a variable containing the region name in my PHP script):

```
SELECT S.station_id, S.name, SA.sub_area_name
FROM dev.Station AS S
INNER JOIN dbo.SubArea AS SA ON S.sub_area_id = SA.sub_area_id
WHERE sub_area_name = '$region'
```

I have also tried the following query, but it returns one row for each monthly data associated with a station, which is not really what I am looking for (only looking for something that sends me the names of the stations that have at least one monthly data associated to it, not all rows containing that data):

```
SELECT S.station_id, S.name, SA.sub_area_name
FROM dev.Station AS S
INNER JOIN dbo.SubArea AS SA ON S.sub_area_id = SA.sub_area_id
INNER JOIN data.MonthlyNormalData as MND ON MND.station_id = S.station_id 
WHERE sub_area_name = '$region' AND MND.value IS NOT NULL
```

What would be the query I would need to run to only have one row per station that have a monthly data associated with it within a certain sub area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `DISTINCT` in your second query to remove duplicated rows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are only returning records from the tables `Station` and `SubArea` using `Distinct` will work for you.

```
SELECT distinct S.station_id, S.name, SA.sub_area_name
FROM dev.Station AS S
INNER JOIN dbo.SubArea AS SA ON S.sub_area_id = SA.sub_area_id
INNER JOIN data.MonthlyNormalData as MND ON MND.station_id = S.station_id 
WHERE sub_area_name = '$region' AND MND.value IS NOT NULL
```

Another way to go about it would be to use `exist`

```
SELECT S.station_id, S.name, SA.sub_area_name
FROM dev.Station AS S
INNER JOIN dbo.SubArea AS SA ON S.sub_area_id = SA.sub_area_id
WHERE exists (select 1 from  data.MonthlyNormalData where station_id = S.station_id) and
sub_area_name = '$region'
```